# Can't write function to replicate the functionality of Bash's 'help' command

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to replicate Bash's `help` command in my .zshrc. I thought this would work:

```
function help {
  bash -c "help $@"
}
```

but this only works when I only pass a single argument -- for instance, `help exit`. It does not work when I pass options to `help`, such as `help -m exit` (which works in Bash). However, literally typing `bash -c "help -m exit"` works as expected. I imagine this has something to do with how quoting works in the shell, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the title @duskwuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
function help {
  bash -c "help $*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I understand why `$*` works, but I don't really understand why `$@` doesn't. I could see how in some contexts, such as looping over a list, `$@` and `$*` would be different, but could you explain how they function differently for just dropping the variables into another string?

Comment: $* returns all the passed arguments in one quoted string 
$@ returns them as separate quoted strings and in your case are passed as multiple arguments to bash - the final call seems something like
bash -c "help funcarg1" "funcarg2" "funcargn" 

Probably bash ignores the other parameters.


You can read more here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Comment: `bash` doesn't ignore the other arguments; `$0` is set to `funcarg2` and `$1` is set to `funcargn`. The command you specified to run, `help funcarg1`, does ignore the values of `$0` and `$1`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need help for using zsh, not for bash. Bash doesn't know anything about zsh builtins and features, and the common builtins are different enough to warrant separate documentation pages.

The equivalent of bash's `help` builtin is `run-help`, but it is not active by default. It will also call `man` for you and comes with a few useful wrappers.

TLDR; put this in .zshrc

`autoload -Uz run-help
autoload -Uz run-help-git
autoload -Uz run-help-ip
autoload -Uz run-help-openssl
autoload -Uz run-help-p4
autoload -Uz run-help-sudo
autoload -Uz run-help-svk
autoload -Uz run-help-svn
alias help=run-help`

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Help_command